# Cordova overriding build.gradle

Tags: cordova, repository, build.gradle

I have a cordova project and [due to an error](https://github.com/arnesson/cordova-plugin-firebase/issues/734) I'm getting when building for android, I need to change the order of the plugin repositories listed in `build.gradle`.

This is what cordova spits out by default:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And I need to change it to reverse the oder of the repositories like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Since `build.gradle` is an auto generated file, I don't want to edit it by handle (it's also not currently in source control).

Based on the [cordova docs](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/#extending-buildgradle), I see that they do support editing it through the `build-extras.gradle` file. I tried creating one of these in the same directory as `build.gradle` with the following contents:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

but it didn't work. There doesn't seem to be a lot of documentation on the `build-extras.gradle` file regarding the syntax and what is allowed in it. Do you just put the part of `build.gradle` that you want to replace?

Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Comment: See answer [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/548)

Comment: Yeah I posted that question in github. :) I haven't tried the solution yet but if it works I'll post back here.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that using cordova-android 7.1.4 solves this problem, as it generated a `build.gradle` file with the correct order.

I got the answer from https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/548